# $compile link function apparently not applying scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to compile some HTML on my controller like so:

```
$scope.online = networkService.isOnline();

var wrapper = angular.element(document.createElement("i"));

var compiledContents = $compile($scope.chapter.contents);
var linkedContents = compiledContents($scope);

wrapper.append(linkedContents);

$scope.chapter.linkedContents = wrapper.html();
```

Where the HTML being compiled has a few elements with a `ng-if='online'` there. But the compiled HTML always comes out with those elements commented, as if `online` was not true (which it is - I even got to the point where I added a `console.log(scope.online)` in Angular's $compile function and it printed true).

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your JS code. You need to post your HTML.

Comment: Where are you appending `wrapper` to the actual DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wrapper.html()` gives back a string representing the inner HTML of the element. You are then assigning that string to `$scope.chapter.linkedContents`. Although it is not clear from your question how and where you are actually using `$scope.chapter.linkedContents`, one thing is certain - this string is definitely not "linked" in any way.

The actual "linkedContents" are the elements that should end up in the DOM. In your case, it is the `wrapper` element with its contents, but again - unclear, how, if ever, it ends up in the DOM.

But you shouldn't even be dealing with DOM in a controller. Controllers are DOM agnostic, so right there you should see a big warning sign that you are doing something wrong. Make sure that you understand the role of a controller, a directive, etc...

I think I understand what the problem you are trying to solve. You get some dynamic uncompiled HTML (or actual elements) - i.e. `$scope.chapter.contents` and you need to have it placed in the DOM and compiled/linked.

Typically, to bind HTML one would use `ng-bind-html` (assuming it's either trusted or sanitization is on):

```
<div ng-bind-html="chapter.contents">
</div>
```

But this would not be $compiled. To compile, I'd suggest writing your own directive that would work similar to `ng-bind-html`, but would also compile it:

```
<div compile-html="chapter.contents">
</div>
```

Then, the directive would take the content, compile/link it against some scope (say, child scope) and append it to the element hosting the directive `compileHtml`.

```
.directive("compileHTML", function($compile, $parse){
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
       // get the HTML content
       var html = $parse(attrs.compileHtml)(scope);

       element.empty();

       // DISCLAIMER: I'm not dealing with sanitization here, 
       // but you should keep it in mind

       $compile(html)(scope, function cloneAttachFn(prelinkContent){
          element.append(prelinkContent);
       });
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: You were right, I was assuming the HTML string I got from the compiled element would be linked and I was using `ng-bind-html` to show it. I changed to attaching the element to the DOM in the controller but your suggestion of using a directive is way better. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, what is the use of `$parse` here? It evaluates a string (compile-html attribute) as an angular expression in the scope that it is passed?

Comment: @Thiatt, yes, it evaluates it once, and avoids a $watch - since in this example, the directive compiles just once and further changes to `chapter.contents` would not be reflected in the DOM